# vertically align span's left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align left side of span to the right end of previous span but it's not working.

Here is a simplified example:
https://jsfiddle.net/regc/udjgufrz/

```
<span class="big">start big</span>
<span class="small">continue with smaller ones. continue with smaller ones. continue with smaller ones. </span>
```

I'd like the smaller text to be vertically aligned to the right of bigger one.

```
BIGGER smaller text
       smaller text
```

I've tried to use divs but in that case the smaller text starts from the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below updated fiddle hope it helps .I used `position:absolute;`

[vertically align span's left Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/udjgufrz/2/)

Comment: thanks happy to help .I added extra margin for good looking .You can customize it as your own. :)

Comment: Yes, that margin was a great touch, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with vertical alignment, it could be like this:

```css
.wrap span {
  display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width:49.5%;
}
.big {
  font-size:50px;
}

.small {
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>here it is:</p>
  <div class="wrap">
      <span class="big">start big</span>
      <span class="small">continue with smaller ones. continue with smaller ones. continue with smaller ones. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I would use `Flexbox`. Is this an option?

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I needed - I wanted the small to start immediately after big

Answer (score 1):

Just simple add `float:left` for `.big` class.

```
.big {
  font-size:50px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udjgufrz/3/